# msg selected items listbox VB.net

Tags: vb.net

i try to show my selected items in message, But it show me as index not items string.

my code :

```
Private Sub listBox1_MouseDoubleClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As MouseEventArgs)
Dim index As Integer = Me.listBox1.IndexFromPoint(e.Location)

If index <> System.Windows.Forms.ListBox.NoMatches Then
    MessageBox.Show(index.ToString())
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why you try to get index location as number?!
try this :

```
    Private Sub listBox1_MouseDoubleClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As MouseEventArgs)

    Dim valuee As String = Me.ListBox1.SelectedItem
    MessageBox.Show(valuee.ToString())

    End Sub
```

hope it what you looking for.